# Force Downloaded CSV File from Server displays the HTML Header script instead, PHP.

Tags: php, download, export-to-csv

I am handed over a PHP Code-igniter project by my Manager, and i have not a dependable experience in PHP. Im trying to download a newly created .csv file from server. But when i download it, it does not have the content of that file, instead it shows the header stript of my .html page where im doing the whole coding.

i am trying this using Force Downloading technique, mentioned all over internet.

```html
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/apps/views/style/Default/files/'.'Attendance'.'_'.strtotime("now").'.csv';
$file = $filename;
if (is_file($file) == true) {
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header("Pragma: public", true);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
      }
```

This code runs on a button click, and the File does download, but it does not show the content, but when i manually download that same file directly from Cpanel server, it has content. 
When i download it through this coding, it has the html scripts. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have the code inside a page, which already have html content displayed or in buffer to be displayed, you will have to implement your force download code inside a blank page or keep the code on top of page, so it give you download of the file content only.

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');

readfile($file);
```